# sort attributes images alphabetically

Tags: magento2.3, attributes

I want to sort alphabetically the manufacturers images list.
I'm using this code and  it generate the order that I have on magento admin

```
get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface::class)
    ->get('manufacturer');

 foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {

    $src = $this->getViewFileUrl('images/' . $option->getLabel() . '.png');


    ?>
   
 " alt="getLabel() ?>" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); " style="padding: 10px 20px;"  width="200" height="200"/>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step - 1
create your own src image array and push the all image link in that array.**

Examp - like this

```
$image_source_files = [];
foreach ($attribute->getOptions() as $option) {

    $src = $option->getLabel() .  '.png';
    $image_source_files[] = $src;
}
```

**Step-2
$image_source_files array sort according to your requirement and check the $image_source_files array using print.**

```
sort($image_source_files);
echo "Standard sorting: ";
print_r($image_source_files);
echo "<br>";

natsort($image_source_files);
echo "Natural order: ";
print_r($image_source_files);
```

foreach ($image_source_files as $value) {
echo $this->getViewFileUrl( $value) ;
}

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you tell me how to put the result of sorting on images src?

Comment: I have already print the array you can check. You can just used for each for new created $image_source_files.

Comment: i tested your code and I have as a result I have something like this:Array ( [0] => https://example.com/images/ .png [1] => https://https://example.com/images/...Merci.png ..... I want to put that on image src in order to display all image of eatch array element! help please

Comment: I have upadate the answer

Comment: but for me I want to sort images not  just their names, how can I put every single array item in src of each image please?

Comment: After you used $this->getViewFileUrl function

Comment: where please? can you be more clear please!

Comment: Plese check updated answer I have put into the answer.

Comment: foreach ($image_source_files as $value) { echo $this->getViewFileUrl( $value) ; }

Comment: Thank you very much